# Open File For Reading Thats Being Written To By OBS

Tags: java, file-io

For anyone that's familiar with the open streaming software OBS (Open Broadcast Software), you would know they have a Start Recording( Live Capture ) feature.

I want to grab that live capture and read in it's bytes for further manipulation on my end without toying with the actual file being created.

The problem persists in that the error message (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) is being presented and it always errors on:

```java
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

File being the location to the live file being written to.

I was wondering what possible work arounds could there be? If the file is open for writing and possibly reading, shouldn't I have access to it only for reading purposes? I have also tried BufferedReader as well to combat this issue.

---

VLC gave this error when trying to open it as well, could be a simple permission block?

```
File reading failed:
VLC could not open the file "D:\Raw Clips\Local Recordings\Hello(01).flv" (Permission denied).

Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///D:/Raw%20Clips/Local%20Recordings/Hello%20%2801%29.flv'. Check the log for details.
```

Comment: OS?  That matters here.

Comment: Windows 10, I'm not going to be surprised if it's Windows causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

So for everyone wondering, the issue lies in OBS Classic where the File seems to be restricted and not shared.
The developer Jim as instructed me to change the Source/MP4FileStream.cpp line 154 to

```
if(!fileOut.Open(lpFile, XFILE_SHARED, 1024*1024))
```

Where the shared should allow the file to be open for reading, OBS Studio doesn't follow suit on this problem.